# List of Dymola flags

Tags: dymola

Some settings in Dymola can be altered by setting flags in the "Commands" window:

[image: Dymola screenshot Flags]

Some examples for flags are:

- `Advanced.AutoFormatting`
- `Advanced.PedanticModelica`
- `Advanced.LogStartValuesForIterationVariables`
- `Hidden.PrintFailureToDifferentiate`

Is there a comprehensive list of all Dymola flags?
Or, even better, a command to print such a list?
Or, even better, something like the `about:config` in Firefox?

Especially, I would like to change the default setting for the `Save contents in one file` checkbox to `Directories - No Questions` because version control software (git in my case) works better with many small files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Dymola 2018 (and may be an earlier versions) there is a flag called `Advanced.DefaultStoreAsOneFile`. Setting to false will enable to save packages as directories.

This flag can be set via GUI as well, see *Edit* > *Options*..., and in the pop-up window, the Tab *Version*, uncheck *As default store packages as one file*. In this way, the setting will be saved in your `setup.dymx` (`setup.mos` in former Dymola versions) file and will thus not affect the Dymola for other users. You can also find some more flags in that file.

But I would suggest to split this question into two ones since there are two topics treated in just one thread.

Comment: That flag is also available in Dymola 2017 and 2017 FD01. Did not test earlier versions.

Answer (score 6):

The `Save contents in one file` checkbox cannot be changed by flags, but by (un)commenting the line `Dymola5StoreOnOneFile 0` in the file `$Dymola$\insert\dymodraw.ini`.

But many other settings can be changed using flags. Use `list()` to print a list of flags (unfortunately, `Hidden.` flags are not included in that list) or use `help()` to get more help.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

In recent Dymola versions there is user dialog with filter function for all flags. You can find it at
Tools → Options → Variables.

[image]

[image: Dymola Screenshot Flags and Variables]

Comment: Yes, found it there too. The "Non-Default" checkbox at the top right is also very useful.

Comment: Even though I prefer finding it in this way you _can_ in Dymola 2023x also find it in "File>Variables" (to the right at the bottom).